# Check for non file-system request in block driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver

I have to make a Disk On Ram block device driver.

From what I understand, every-time the kernel decides to perform block IO on our device, a request function is called. It has a prototype

```
static void my_request(struct request_queue *q)
```

We tell the kernel that this is the request function by using the `blk_init_queue` function.

Now, from the examples that I have read, what `my_request` is supposed to do is iterate over the request queue by using `blk_fetch_request`, It has to **discard non-fs requests** and perform the actual transfers for other kinds of requests.

My question is how does the driver know if a request is a non-fs request.

Here's what I know:

There used to be a function(or macro?) called `blk_fs_request` in something like this:

```
if (! blk_fs_request(req)) {
        end_request(req, 0);
        continue;
}
```

> A nonzero return value from the blk_fs_request() macro says "this is a
>   normal filesystem request." Other types of requests (i.e. packet-mode
>   or device-specific diagnostic operations) are not something that sbd
>   supports, so it simply fails any such requests. (from lwn.net [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/25415/))

(sbd stands for simple block device. the author is trying to explain the new interface using an example).

In the kernel version that I am using (output of `uname -r: 4.15.0-46-generic`), there is no such function as `blk_fs_request`. I read around and found that the function has been removed.

There was a workaround where drivers would simply read `req->cmd_type` for the same functionality but that member has been removed from `struct request` as well.

So, my question is, without `blk_fs_request` and `req->cmd_type` is there a way i can detect non file system requests, or should I just assume all requests to be file system requests and process them.

Comment: I think `blk_rq_is_passthrough(req)` is more-or-less the opposite of the old `blk_fs_request(req)`. `blk_fs_request` was removed in 2.6.36 ([commit 33659ebbae262228eef4e0fe990f393d1f0ed941](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=33659ebbae262228eef4e0fe990f393d1f0ed941)). `blk_rq_is_passthrough` was added in 4.11 ([commit aebf526b53aea164508730427597d45f3e06b376](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=aebf526b53aea164508730427597d45f3e06b376)).

Comment: What are the differences if any?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with the block layer. Most of my stuff tends to be character special device drivers.

Comment: "make a Disk On Ram block device driver" why?  What's wrong with the ones already in the kernel?

Comment: as a learning assignment